# how do we bootstrap the cosmosdb client?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0

**how do we use DI to bootstrap the cosmos client at startup?**

This is what I have so far:

```
    services.AddSingleton(s => {
        var connectionString = Configuration["CosmosDBConnection"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Please specify a valid CosmosDBConnection in the appSettings.json file or your Azure Functions Settings.");
        }

        return new CosmosClientBuilder(connectionString)
            .Build();
    });
```

How do I use this cosmos db client in my code?

Comment: Can't you just do this in the class that wants to use it?
       
   private readonly CosmosClient _cosmosClient;

        public MyFunc(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
        {
            _cosmosClient = cosmosClient;
        }

Comment: sure but what if my controller wants to use it

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://github.com/ealsur/ondotnet-cosmosdb/tree/master/src/episode1/streams

Once you register the object on the DI container, you can just pull it on your Controller declaration:

```
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    private readonly CosmosClient client;
    public ItemController(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
    {
        this.client = cosmosClient;
    }
}
```